# Empty or reset entire array with button

Tags: javascript

This is my script might be easier to explain if yas can see it, im tring to reset the array with a button

```
 <body> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
   var number = []; 

   function myFunction() 
   { 
     var x = document.getElementById("box"); 
     number.push(document.getElementById("input").value); 
     x.innerHTML = number.join('<br/>');  
   } 


  </script> 
 <form> 
  <input id="input" type=text> 
   <input type=button onclick="myFunction()" value="Add to list"/>  
  </form>

 <div id="box" style="border:1px solid black;width:150px;height:150px;overflow:scroll">  
  </div> 
<form>
<input type=button onclick="number.splice(0)" value="Reset" />
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Lots of misspelling in the code. Could be the reason..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Call it from a function.

EDIT: splice has problems with IE. Use array.length = 0 instead

```
<body> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var number = []; 

        function myFunction() { 
            var x = document.getElementById("box"); 
            number.push(document.getElementById("input").value); 
            x.innerHTML = number.join('<br/>');  
        } 

        function myReset() {
            //number.splice(0);
            number.length = 0;
            var x = document.getElementById("box"); 
            x.innerHTML = "";
            x.innerHTML = number.join('<br/>');  
        }
    </script> 

    <form> 
        <input id="input" type=text> 
        <input type=button onclick="myFunction()" value="Add to list"/>  
    </form>

    <div id="box" style="border:1px solid black;width:150px;height:150px;overflow:scroll">  
    </div> 
    <form>
        <input type=button onclick="myReset()" value="Reset" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: oh no its nt working on IE9 works on firefox i will try find a solution on net

Comment: got it to work                                                      function myReset() { 
            number=[]
         number.splice(0); 
            var x = document.getElementById("box");  
            x.innerHTML = ""; 
            x.innerHTML = number.join('<br/>');   
        }

Answer (score 0):

Despite being ugly, `onclick="number.splice(0)"` works: http://jsfiddle.net/39KZ9/20/

Comment: no, `number=[]` creates a **new** array.  Any existing references to the old array will be unaltered.

Comment: thanks for your replys sorry about the spelling mistakes staying up studying all nights doin my head in, i tryed with out spelling mistakes still didnt work, i tryed the onclick="number.splice(0)" still didnt work do i need to call it from a function i will post my code